# How can i list an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two objects of `person`:

```
var p1 = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
var p2 = {firstName:"Joanne", lastName:"Doe", age:43};
```

How can i add these objects to a `persons` array and access it by index?

All i know is to initialized the `persons`:

```
var persons = [
    {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46},
    {firstName:"Joanne", lastName:"Doe", age:43}
];
```

Comment: `var persons = [p1, p2]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create an array of persons:

```
var persons = []; // initialize the array

persons.push({firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46}); // Add an object

persons.push({firstName:"Joanne", lastName:"Doe", age:43}); // Add another object
```

To retrieve the value at a specific index:

```
persons[1].firstName // "Joanne"
persons[1].lastName  // "Doe"
persons[1].age       // 43
```

To iterate through the array use a `for` loop, or any kind of loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    console.log( persons[i].firstName ); // writes first names to console
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an [array literal use `[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax) instead of `{}`.

Comment: i just found that syntax here http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_object

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab — Which is the right syntax to create an object. Then you tried to put the objects in an array and you used the wrong syntax to create the array.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab — You seem to have edited the question to fix the syntax. So now the code in the question works. The question doesn't appear to be asking anything now.

Comment: i do not ask for the initialization sir i asked for the insert of an array object

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab — Your code is creating an array and inserting two objects into it. I still don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: some one leads me to `push` syntax sir.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab — That's nice. I still don't understand what problem you are having.

Comment: the case is i want to get the html table data to js array so i have trouble adding the data by initializing inside the foreach loop so the `push` method works great!

Comment: What foreach loop? There's no foreach loop in the question!

Answer (score 1):

You can add each object by using the `push` method.
Cycle through your array and for each one `persons.push(object)`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to iterate through an array of these people is:

```
const people = persons.map((person, i) => {
  console.log(persons[i].firstName)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **push** method
It will add the object to the end of the array.

see example:

```html
<script>
var per1 ={firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46};
var per2 ={firstName:"Johny", lastName:"Doe", age:50};
var persons = [per1,per2];

var per3 ={firstName:"Johnonon", lastName:"Doe", age:52};
persons.push(per3);

</script>
```